# How to check if property only belongs to the child class or subclass in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get properties (excluding functions) those are only present in a subclass (child class) and not in the parent class in Javascript. I am using `.hasOwnProperty()` but it is also gives `true` for parent class's properties. I am running this in node.

Code:

```
class Model{
  constructor(){
    this.location = 'Gotham'
  }
}

class Superhero extends Model{
}

const superhero = new Superhero()
superhero.alias = 'Batman'
superhero.realName = 'Bruce Wayne'

for (const property in superhero){
  if (superhero.hasOwnProperty(property) && (typeof superhero[property] !== 'function')){
    console.log(`${property} = ${superhero[property]}`)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
location = Gotham
alias = Batman
realName = Bruce Wayne
```

Output I want to get:

```
alias = Batman
realName = Bruce Wayne
```

Please help!!

Comment: There's no real way to know, since even `this.location = ...` essentially is the same as `superhero.location = ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your properties is on the "parent" or "child" class, they're all on the **instance** (object) created via `new Superhero`. There is no way to tell, looking at the instance, that `location` was added to the instance by the `Model` constructor but the other two were added to it by the `Superhero` constructor. That information is just not part of the object model in JavaScript.

As of where you start your loop, here's what you have in memory (with some details omitted):

```
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Model−−−−−−>| (function) |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                      
            | prototype  |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>|   (object)    |                      
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+                          /    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                      
                                                    |    | [[Prototype]] |−−−−>Object.prototype
                                                    |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                      
                                                    |
                                                    |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+                          |
Superhero−−>| (function) |                          |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
            | prototype  |−−−−+−>|   (object)    |  |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−+   /   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                             |   | [[Prototype]] |−−+
                             |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                             |
                             +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                          \
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
superhero−−>|         (object)        |   |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
            | [[Prototype]]           |−−−+
            | location: "Gotham"      |
            | alias:    "Batman"      |
            | realName: "Bruce Wayne" |
            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

As you can see, all the properties are on the instance itself.

If `instance` were on a *prototype* of the instance, you'd be able to differentiate them, but not with what you have where they're all properties on the instance itself.

You can move `location` to a prototype (specifically, the prototype of the prototype of the instance) by making it an *accessor property*:

```js
class Model {
  constructor() {
    // This makes _location non-enumerable and non-configurable
    Object.defineProperty(this, "_location", {
      value: "Gotham",
      writable: true
    });
  }
  get location() {
    return this._location;
  }
  set location(value) {
    this._location = value;
  }
}
// Make our "location" accessor property enumerable (if you want it to be).
// By default, accessors defined in class notation are non-enumerable.
{
  const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Model.prototype, "location");
  desc.enumerable = true;
  Object.defineProperty(Model.prototype, "location", desc);
}

class Superhero extends Model {
}

const superhero = new Superhero();
superhero.alias = 'Batman';
superhero.realName = 'Bruce Wayne';

for (const property in superhero){
  if (superhero.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof superhero[property] !== 'function') {
    console.log(`${property} = ${superhero[property]}`)
  }
}
```

In that example, since we have to store the value of `location` somewhere, I created a `_location` property to store it in. That's still on the instance, though, and could be set without going through the accessors. (It doesn't show up in the `for-in` loop because I made it non-enumerable.) If we wanted to really protect it, we'd have to store it separately from the instance, probably by using a `WeakMap` keyed by the instance itself. But going that far isn't usually necessary.

Comment: +1                                                                                for using `[[prototype]]` instead of `__proto__` :D

Comment: @Bergi - :-) Well, in theory, Node.js-hosted code shouldn't have `__proto__`. But in any case, I stick to the non-Annex-B stuff wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in T.J. Crowder's great explanation, `location` belongs to child subclass, because when child class is instantiated, `location` is set on child class instance (`this`).

A simple way to make a property belong to parent class is to set it on class prototype:

```
class Model{}
Model.prototype.location = 'Gotham';

class Superhero extends Model{}

// 'location' in new Superhero() === true
// new Superhero().hasOwnProperty('location') === false
```